# Camera doesnt follow custom character?

Tags: roblox

I made a click script that changes the player's character into a zombie if they click on it, it almost works but the camera doesnt follow the player's new character, the workspace's camera subject is still the player's old humanoid

Script:

```
script.Parent.MouseClick:Connect(function(plr)
if plr.Team == game.Teams.Mastermind then
    script.Parent.Parent:WaitForChild("AI Chase"):Destroy()
    script.Parent.MaxActivationDistance = 0
    script.Parent:WaitForChild("RemoteEvent"):FireClient(plr)
    wait(0.5)
    plr.Character = script.Parent.Parent
end
end)
```

Local script:

```
local debounce = false

script.Parent.MouseClick:Connect(function(plr)
if plr.Team == game.Teams.Mastermind then
    if not debounce then
        debounce = true
        repeat wait() workspace.Camera.CameraType = Enum.CameraType.Fixed until workspace.Camera.CameraType == Enum.CameraType.Fixed
        workspace.Camera.CameraSubject = script.Parent.Parent.PrimaryPart
    end
end
end)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind i made a remote event fire and set the workspace's camera subject to the new character's humanoid, its working now!

Comment: You can explain your answer as it's unclear right now. This will help future readers. Do accept it!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I forgot to accept it lol, thanks for reminding me!